# How do I identify where a "NSArrayM was mutated while being enumerated" is coming from

Tags: ios, objective-c

I sometimes get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 
'*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x170057580> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

I understand that I'm mutating an array while using fast enumeration, but I can't figure out how to identify **where** this issue is happening. The stack trace shows me absolutely nothing, and other than just randomly setting breakpoints and guessing until I find it, I can't figure out a good way to zero in on where this is happening.

Is there some kind of breakpoint magic I can do so the compiler shows me where this happens? Or can I use NSZombies to somehow identify this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look into your code where you have `addObject` or `removeObject` and similar methods inside the fast enumeration blocks

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @Merlevede, things aren't actually that simple. I have a game where nodes are manipulated during an update loop, and these nodes have children, grandchildren, and so on. It's very hard to identify exactly where this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See how to set an exception breakpoint:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

But in the latest Xcode you only need to do these steps:

> In the bottom-left corner of the breakpoints navigator, click the Add button.
>
> Choose Add Exception Breakpoint.

You then get this in the breakpoint navigator

[image]

Your code will now break when the exception is thrown rather than when it is caught. You should be able to navigate the call stack to see where in your code the exception is occurring.

Comment: I feel like this is something I should have understood a long time ago. Thank you though; this was exactly what I was looking for.